# How to Change custom post type Dashicon Color

Tags: theme-development, dashboard, icon

I have seen some example of changing custom Post Type icon colors but nothing for using wp builtin `dashicon`. I also tried to do this

```
.dashicons { color: red; }
```

which is only changing color of dashicons in the page not in the menu, besides I just want to change A custom post type dashicon color not all of them (to be highlighted). For example for the CPT Movies only. Can you please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu icons are displayed via CSS in the `:before` pseudo-element of the `.wp-menu-image.dashicons-before` wrapper.
So first your code needs to target `.wp-menu-image:before`, or `.dashicons-before:before` (not `.dashicons`).

This won't be enough though because default styles in WordPress are using some more specific selectors. Though you could override them with `!important` and make all icons red with this:

`.wp-menu-image:before { color: red !important; }`

(Note that this should be avoided whenever possible.)

But this is not what you are asking for here, you want to color only the icon for one specific custom post type.

You'll need make your selector more specific to target your custom post type menu item.

If your custom post type slug is `cpt_movie`, this will do:

`.menu-icon-cpt_movie .wp-menu-image:before { color: red; }`

You may also want another color when you mouse-hover the menu item:

`.menu-icon-cpt_movie:hover .wp-menu-image:before { color: green; }`

Related quick tip: play around with your browser's DevTools, it makes it really easy to work out which elements/classes you need to target in css ;)